# Xcode 11: "SimulatorTrampoline.xpc" wants to access files managed by "iCloud Drive"

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode11

Recently updated to Xcode 11 GM seed 2 (`11A420a`) and I when running my app on a simulator (`iPhone Xs Max` (probably irrelevant)) a dialog popped up asking permission to access my iCloud.

Why? Apple did not provide any reason as to why which felt strange?

> "SimulatorTrampoline.xpc" wants to access files managed by "iCloud Drive".

I actually accepted... because I did not want any strange incorrect behavior of my simulator.

But feels kind of ironic that Apple forces us, developers, to provide reasons (displayed to users of our apps) why we want to access the user's camera for instance, but here Apple did not provide any reason text themselves...

Comment: SimulatorTrampoline is a proxy that takes responsibility for all processes inside the simulator. It doesn't know why simulator processes want access so it can't provide a reason. If it didn't exist you'd get prompted many more times. For some reasources (like Microphone) you'd get a macOS prompt and an iOS prompt inside the sim.

Comment: That's a lame excuse. The reason could simply be that the Xcode Simulator would like access to your "whatever". Or an explanation like you just gave about what SimulatorTrampoline is. No explanation is much worse than either of those. There's nothing wrong with explaining what the root reason for the message is. Even a link to an article would be better than what is produced now. And why do I get the popup when I'm not even using Xcode actively?

Comment: Something along these lines would be better: When building for the first time users may get a popup stating that SimulatorTrampoline would like access to Desktop Files because ibtool running in simulator needs access to these files to compile storyboards. (51114450)
Workaround: Allow access to the files in the prompt. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_release_notes

Answer (score 18):

You are officially recommended to click "Allow/Ok" by Apple (as a "workaround").

This is a "KNOWN ISSUE" per ..

.. Apple's OWN formal release-notes @ https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-11-release-notes

Comment: This is a good point, but I am getting the same issue now with Xcode 14.3 and I did not install an update it recently, but the simulator is running for a few days in the background, suddenly I get prompted for the file access, does anybody have the same issue?

Comment: The referenced text is "When building for the first time users may get a popup stating that SimulatorTrampoline would like access to Desktop Files because ibtool running in simulator needs access to these files to compile storyboards." But my prompt wants access to “iCloud Drive”.  I have no relevant files in “iCloud Drive” so I chose "don't allow". Have not noticed any side effects, and will hopefully stay that way. Running Simulator Version 15.0 (1015.2).  Seems like this bug is still around...

Comment: It feels really strange to see the simulator ask for this. It sometimes asks for some other permissions too. I immediately started wondering if any of my react-native libraries are doing something fishy from a security perspective. Still not sure what's going on, but the fact that this is a known issue from Apple makes me really nervous about conditioning users to always press "Allow" on dialogs they don't understand.

Comment: It is still happening with Xcode 15.2 asking for "iCloud Drive". I'm sorry, nothing to see there, move along! < Don't Allow >